# Query to get subjects of interest for all User Y where Y shares >=3 interests with a User X

Tags: mysql, sql

These are two tables from a part of supposed Twitter like database where users can follow other users. The User.name field is unique.

```
mysql> select uID, name from User;
+-----+-------------------+
| uID | name              |
+-----+-------------------+
|   1 | Alice             |
|   2 | Bob               |
|   5 | Iron Maiden       |
|   4 | Judas Priest      |
|   6 | Lesser Known Band |
|   3 | Metallica         |
+-----+-------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from Follower;
+-----------+------------+
| subjectID | observerID |
+-----------+------------+
|         3 |          1 |
|         4 |          1 |
|         5 |          1 |
|         6 |          1 |
|         3 |          2 |
|         4 |          2 |
|         5 |          2 |
+-----------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> call newFollowSuggestionsForName('Bob');
+-------------------+
| name              |
+-------------------+
| Lesser Known Band |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to make an operation that will suggest for a user X a list of users they may be interested in following. I thought one heuristic could be to show X for all y who user y follows where X and y follow at least 3 of the same Users. Below is the SQL I came up with to do this. My question is if it could be done more efficiently or nicer in some other ways.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE newFollowSuggestionsForName(IN in_name CHAR(60))
BEGIN

DECLARE xuid INT;
SET xuid = (select uID from User where name=in_name);  

select name
from User, (select subjectID
            from follower
            where observerID in (
                select observerID
                from Follower
                where observerID<>xuid and subjectID in (select subjectID from Follower where observerID=xuid)
                group by observerID
                having count(*)>=3
            )
    ) as T
where uID = T.subjectID and not exists (select * from Follower where subjectID=T.subjectID and observerID=xuid);

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why do you input `in_name` as Char. You must be having its integer ID value also. My suggestion is to use that instead. It will be more performant. Moreoever, what happens if there are two users with same name(s) ?

Comment: Also, do you have access to latest version of MySQL (version 8.0.2 and above) ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following refactored SQL code (untested without data) for use in stored procedure.

```
select u.`name`
from `User` u
inner join 
   (select subf.observerID, subf.subjectID
    from follower subf
    where subf.observerID <> xuid
   ) f
on u.UID = f.subjectID 
inner join 
   (select f1.observerID
    from follower f1
    inner join follower f2
      on f1.subjectID = f2.subjectID 
     and f1.observerID <> xuid
     and f2.observerID = xuid
    group by f1.observerID
    having count(*) >= 3
   ) o
on f.observerID = o.observerID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the basic query starts as getting all "observers" who share three "subjects" with a given observer:

```
select f.observerid
from followers f join
     followers f2
     on f.subjectid = f2.subjectid and
        f2.observerid = 2
group by f.observerid
having count(*) = 3;
```

The rest of the query is just joining in the names to fit into your paradigm of using names for references rather than ids.